# Simulate several clicks when the mouse button is held

Tags: c++, linux, windows, click, x11

I've been searching for a long time how to simulate mouse left and right clicks when the user is holding down the mouse button on Linux/Windows.

I tried using a python library called [PyUserInput](https://github.com/PyUserInput/PyUserInput) which is a binding to X11 and it worked but only when I wasn't holding down the mouse button, so I think that if I use C++ and the X11 library, then I will have the same problem.

This is the code I used with the [PyUserInput](https://github.com/PyUserInput/PyUserInput) library, it simulates a click each half second, but the click doesn't work when we are pressing the left mouse button:

```
from pymouse import PyMouse
from time import sleep

mouse = PyMouse()

# Simulates a click by using the PyUserInput library
def click():
        x, y = mouse.position()
        mouse.click(x, y)

while True:
        click()
        sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: i'm not understanding your question. What do you mean by "button is hold"? A keyboard button? A GUI button?

Comment: You'll need to show us your code, it's not clear what you're trying to do. It looks like you want a mouse to click if you're holding down a key, is that correct?

Comment: @gbalduzzi By button is hold I meant when you pressed the left mouse button without releasing it.

Comment: @TankorSmash I want a way to simulate a left click while the left click button of my mouse is pressed.

Comment: Isn't the trivial solution then to not simulate anything?

Comment: @IInspectable No I want a click even if the user's left mouse button is pressed. Maybe I could try simulating a release event.

Comment: In other words: You want the same as key repeat, but for the mouse button? Key repeat is a system feature, implemented through `SendInput`. At a guess i would assume, that it injects key-up, key-down until the key is released.

Comment: @IInspectable Sorry if I'm not clear enough. What I meant is that I am doing a program to click automatically for me when I want. It works very well, except when the left mouse button is pressed.

Comment: Using XTEST doesn't work either. You could try if Xinput2 can do anything, but I doubt it. This might be something you'd have to go into the kernel for.

Comment: Any idea how to perform such task without the necessity of using external libraries/tools?